# Why is a cell valid but its elements are nil after creation

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

This question applies to tableViews and to collectionViews.

Lets talk about a collection view using a prototype cell.

Suppose the prototype cell is assigned to `MyCollectionViewCell` class.

Suppose that this class has two properties: `countryName` and `countryImage` (a label and a imageView, respectively).

Why I cannot assign values for name and country during this method? and what is the best way to solve that?

During this method...

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

  MyCollectionViewCell *cell = (MyCollectionViewCell *)[collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

  NSArray *section = self.arrayData[indexPath.section];

  NSDictionary *itemOnSection = section[indexPath.row];

  // Configure the cell
  UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:itemOnSection[@"image"]];
  NSString *name = itemOnSection[@"name"];

  cell.countryImage.image = image;
  cell.countryName.text = name;

  return cell;
}
```

what will happen with this method is that cell will be a valid object but `cell.countryImage` and `cell.countryName` will be `nil`.

what I don't understand is this: if the cell exists and is a valid object according to the debugger, why its elements are not initialized. What is the best way to solve that?

this is MyCollectionViewCell.h

```
@interface MyCollectionViewCell : UICollectionViewCell

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *countryImage;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *countryName;


@end
```

the outlets are connected to the elements on the prototype cell and the prototype cell has this class assigned.

MyCollectionViewCell.m has nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the UICollectionView documentations is section about the cell.

According to the cell:

> Return Value The cell object at the corresponding index path or nil if
>   the cell is not visible or indexPath is out of range.

Probably you have problem of setting resource in

> MyCollectionViewCell

**Firstly create property in you're cell**

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString   *countryNameTitle;
```

**Than method to set name**

```
//method to set name that should be called from cellForItemAtIndexPath
-(void)setCountryName
{
  if ([countryNameTitle length] != 0)
  {
     countryName.text = countryNameTitle;
  }
}
```

**And than set name from delegate**

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

  MyCollectionViewCell *cell = (MyCollectionViewCell *)[collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

  NSArray *section = self.arrayData[indexPath.section];

  NSDictionary *itemOnSection = section[indexPath.row];

  // Configure the cell
  UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:itemOnSection[@"image"]];
  NSString *name = itemOnSection[@"name"];

  cell.countryImage.image = image;
  cell.countryNameTitle = name;
  [cell setCountryName];


  return cell;
}
```

Comment: ok, but the cell is not nil. Nil are the cell's label and imageView. This is what I don't understand. If the cell object is valid why its properties are nil?

Comment: I have added more code to the question but it is probably not be visible until someone with more reputation approves it. All I have is the outlets to the imageView and countryName label connected to properties on the MyCollectionViewCell class and the prototype cell assigned to that class.

Comment: in you're m file add #pragma mark - View Lifecycle

- (void)awakeFromNib
{
    [super awakeFromNib];
} and call it [cell awakeFromNib];

Comment: Double check your reUseIdentifier in the dequeue method.  Does it match the value in your storyboard?

Comment: everything is fine but it is not working as expected.

Answer (score 1):

How are you registering views to be used by the collection view?

If you want to use a cell defined in a nib/xib, you will have to:

```
registerNib:forCellWithReuseIdentifier:
```

as opposed to

```
registerClass:forCellWithReuseIdentifier:
```

This should then ensure the cell sets up any outlets :)